# TSQL Multiple search condition on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2012.

On our web page we have multiple textbox. User can enter in and one and click search or enter in couple of text box and click search...

- First Name
- Last Name
- Address line
- Employee Code
- Language ... (total 7 text box)

Sample T-SQL :

```
WHERE FirstName = @FirstName
```

If `@firstname` is not entered in textbox then I don't want it to be part of the `where` clause

```
  AND LastName = @LastName
```

Same here: if last name is not entered in text box then I don't want it to be include in the `where` clause

... and so On

Issue: all these tables hold more than a million rows, so I cannot use case statement in where clause due to performance impact

So is there any other approach that I can take to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the same result by using full-text search. Then you don't have to create dynamic quarry as well. And the search is quite fast due to it using different service.

First, you have to create a FullTextCatalog then add tables and columns to it (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15)

I have used AdventureWorks db to write a demo. You can convert this code according to your table and columns. I have just added 3 columns here and you can add all your columns to full-text.

```
USE [AdventureWorks2016]
GO

/****** Object:  FullTextCatalog [SearchEmp]    Script Date: 6/24/2020 8:11:33 AM ******/
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [SearchEmp] WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = ON
GO

**strong text**
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [Person].[Person](
[FirstName] LANGUAGE 'English', 
[LastName] LANGUAGE 'English', 
[MiddleName] LANGUAGE 'English')
KEY INDEX [PK_Person_BusinessEntityID]ON ([SearchEmp], FILEGROUP [PRIMARY])
WITH (CHANGE_TRACKING = AUTO, STOPLIST = SYSTEM)



  GO

Declare @FirstName Nvarchar(200)='KEN'
Declare @LastName  nvarchar(200)='Sánchez'
Declare @Searchtext nvarchar(400)

-- build search text avoid spaces and special characters in words
SET @Searchtext= concat(TRIM(@FirstName),' OR ', TRIM(@LastName)) 

--- First and Last Name
select top 3 * from [Person].[Person]
where Contains((FirstName,LastName),@Searchtext)

--First Name
SET @Searchtext=@FirstName
select top 3 * from [Person].[Person]
where Contains((FirstName,LastName),@Searchtext)

--Last Name
SET @Searchtext=@LastName
select  top 3* from [Person].[Person]
where Contains((FirstName,LastName),@Searchtext)

-- use ContainsTable
SET @Searchtext=@LastName
select top 3 * from ContainsTable([Person].[Person],(FirstName,LastName),@Searchtext) CT
Inner join [Person].[Person] P ON CT.[Key] = P.BusinessEntityID
```

[image]

you can order your results using weight ([SQL Server Weighted Full Text Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310425/sql-server-weighted-full-text-search))

Comment: Fulltext search very good idea, but you should try this query in dynamic query for give one select result.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work for you.

```
  SELECT FirstName,
   LastName,
   Address1,
   EmployeeCode,
   OtherFields
   FROM SomeTable
   WHERE ((@FirstName IS NULL) OR ( FirstName = @FirstName)) AND
   ((@LastName IS NULL) OR ( LastName = @LastName)) AND
   ((@Address1 IS NULL) OR ( Address1 = @Address1)) AND
   ((@EmployeeCode IS NULL) OR ( EmployeeCode = @EmployeeCode))
```

Comment: Found a good article based on this solution http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a [table-valued function](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-user-defined-functions/sql-server-table-valued-functions/) for example :

```
CREATE FUNCTION udfSearchEmployee (
    @FirstName varchar(255),
    @Lastname varchar(255),
    ...
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN

SELECT FirstName,
       LastName,
       AddressLine,
       EmployeeCode,...
       FROM YourTable
 --To make your query SARGable
       WHERE ((@FirstName IS NULL) OR ( FirstName = @FirstName)) AND
       ((@LastName IS NULL) OR ( LastName = @LastName)) AND
       ((@AddressLine IS NULL) OR ( AddressLine = @Address1)) AND
       ((@EmployeeCode IS NULL) OR ( EmployeeCode = @EmployeeCode)) ...
```